# It doesn't always scroll to the same place, Appium Android

Tags: appium, appium-android, android-uiautomator, appium-java

I am using the following method while scrolling android. but It doesn't always scroll to the same place, even though it's on the same page. what would be the reason.

```
public void ScrollToCampaignNotice(){
    try {
        getDriver().findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator(
                "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).flingToEnd(35)"));
    } catch (InvalidSelectorException e) {
        // ignore
   

 }
    }
```

At the same time, I tried the following method differently, it has the same problem.

[image]

Comment: you should scroll to the exact element rather then fling 35 (max) times

Comment: @RolandasUlevicius how can i do it can you write sample code

Answer (score 2):

You could scroll to exact element instead of flinging 35 times.

Here is an example how to scroll to specific text that is visible:

```
new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains("<include your text>").instance(0))
```

You can also scroll to an element that has specific id like this:

```
new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId("<insert element ID here>").instance(0))
```

Comment: Thanks for support but when i try this method works is very slow I recorded video Is there any way I can speed this up?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MZeJIkpklV1AtqdfMTk6kOjb1y5RqLBV/view

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest android UiAutomator2 mobile command and remember it works with only UiSelector (best), accessibility id, and class name.

```
HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("strategy", "-android uiautomator");
map1.put("selector", "UiSelector().text(\"Art of Asia\")");

driver.executeScript("mobile: scroll", map1);

driver.findElement(AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator("UiSelector().text(\"Art of Asia\")")).click();
```